# Pytezos for originating contracts

Tags: smart-contracts, michelson, python

I am quite new to Pytezos and I have a few questions and would be very happy if you could help me.
I want to make my script buy NFT, I know the smart contract address, how could I get from smart contract all the fields which needs to be filled and how do I originate contract using Pytezos? Do I have to convert it to michelson and use Tezos-client?
Is there any way to send commands on Tezos-client using python?

Thank you for you time!

Answer (score 2):

You can get the contract script and use it for the origination:

```
kolibri_oven = pytezos.using('mainnet').contract('KT1KH3wH4sneEevPVW7AACiVKMjhTvmXLSK6')
initial_storage = {}
pytezos.origination(script = kolibri_oven.script(initial_storage), balance = 0).autofill().sign().inject()
```

Read more: https://pytezos.org/quick_start.html#originate-contract

Comment: Hey, thank you for you answer. I got one more question. How do I buy NFT on secondary market, like from objkt.com, do I still use same contract, and how can I specify which "name or number" of NFT I want to buy?